# error while saving video stream in pickle file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, pickle

i am trying to stream from webcam to another computer and save the stream in a pickle file in numpy array. i will later process the frames in iskits library. ****i m sending strings from sender and convert it in numpy array and save it to pickle file.****

but when i try to load stream from .pkl file it is showing error.
when i try to print the size of the array it shows 0 or 1 or 2.

```
with open('/home/siplab/samples.pkl','rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
print shape(data)
```

the output shows

```
siplab@siplab-OptiPlex-9020:~$ python gh.py
(2,)
```

the code for client is

```
import socket
import pygame
import sys
import numpy as np
import pickle
host = "127.0.1.1"
port=5000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0)
pygame.display.set_caption('Webcam Viewer')
while True:
     clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     clientsocket.connect((host, port))
     received = []
     while True:
      recvd_data = clientsocket.recv(1024000)
    if not recvd_data:
        break
    else:
        received.append(recvd_data)



dataset = ''.join(received)
image = pygame.image.fromstring(dataset,(640,480),"RGB") 
screen.blit(image,(0,0)) 
pygame.display.update()

k = np.asarray('received',dtype=float,sep=', ')
with open('samples.pkl','wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(k,f) 

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

the code for the server is

```
import socket
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import sys
import time
port = 5000
pygame.init()
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(("127.0.1.1",port))
serversocket.listen(5)
pygame.camera.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
webcam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
webcam.start()
while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    image = webcam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB")
    connection.sendall(data)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    connection.close()
```

Comment: What is the error exactly  ?

Comment: in the .pkl file nothing is saved

Comment: the video is streaming so the strings are sent and the data supposed to save as ndarray in .pkl file. but it isn't. if i save the string only without converting to array then it is stored but i have to save it in array as i have to processed them later.